# Adding JS Function inside Template Literal

Tags: ecmascript-6, i18next, template-literals

I am trying to add .split() function inside template literal.

I would like to add `city = city.split(',')[0]` ... instead of city inside i18n and remove the `city = city.split(',')[0]` before messages. What is the correct syntax in this case?

```
 city = city.split(',')[0]
 messages.push({
  text: `<strong>${i18n.t('text.banner', { defaultValue: `Welcome` })}</strong>
  ${i18n.t('text.message', { defaultValue: '{{city}} is now 65 degrees.', city })}` // I would like to add city = city.split(',')[0] here...
})
```

Comment: why don't you try using the dollar sign for the city too? you're already in a template literal so just put the city.split in `${}` : `${city.split(',')[0]}`. I don't think I fully got what you're doing but I hope this helps

Comment: Can you provide example of what you mean? I'm getting error when replacing {{city}} with ${city.split(',')[0]} ....maybe it's because I am inside template literal already? Do I remove `, city` param?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
messages.push({
  text: `<strong>${i18n.t('text.banner', { defaultValue: `Welcome` })}</strong>
  ${i18n.t('text.message', { defaultValue: city.split(',')[0] + ' is now 65 degrees.'}, city )}` //here city is the third parameter passed to i18n.t()
})
```

if you want `city` to be passed in the second parameter of `i18n.t()` which is inside the object that contains the `defaultValue` then include it in the object:

```
messages.push({
  text: `<strong>${i18n.t('text.banner', { defaultValue: `Welcome` })}</strong>
  ${i18n.t('text.message', { defaultValue: city.split(',')[0] + ' is now 65 degrees.', city})}` //here city is in the same object
})
```

Comment: What if text.message is expecting the parameter though?

Comment: i haven't used i18n, do you mean if `i18n.t()` takes 3 parameters?